# Jasmine test case for anonymous and onload function

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I am having 2 below functions on my .js file

**Anonymous function :**

```
(function(){
    generateDynamicDesign();
    appInit();
    showLoadImg();
    var twitterChannalflag;
})();
```

**Onload function**

```
window.onload(){
    a();
    b();
}
```

I wish to know how can I write a jasmine unit test case for these 2 functions? It is a **pure JavaScript**  project.

Comment: You need to refactor this two functions into accessible functions that you can test. Keep in mind, that if you can't test a function you have a architecture problem or you can refactor your code :)

Comment: Here are two posts that can help you [anonymous function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33744766/unit-testing-javascript-anonymous-functions) , [window.onload](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36401443/how-to-test-code-inside-window-onload-function-in-jasmine)